# ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set

Tags: salesforcedx, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to setup CI/CD with Jenkins for the first time. I already have a valid script running in Bitbucket Pipelines, but now we need to move to the client provided Jenkins server.

This is my script up to the point where it is failing:

```
export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=false
export SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN=true
export SFDX_DOMAIN_RETRY=300
export SFDX_DISABLE_APP_HUB=true
export SFDX_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
sfdx -v

sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid DEVHUB_CONSUMERKEY --jwtkeyfile JWT_KEY_FILE --username DEVHUB_USERNAME --setdefaultdevhubusername -a HubOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com
```

The last line is failing with the following error:

> ERROR running force:auth:jwt:grant:  Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set

However, if I change the `--instanceurl` from `https://login.salesforce.com` to `https://xxx.my.salesforce.com` the script will run fine.

So, I'm trying to understand now why this is happening? As this is not an issue in any other environment where I've used the above script.

P.S. The sfdx version is `sfdx-cli/7.23.1-ced0ec4940 linux-x64 node-v10.15.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://login.salesforce.com` (or `https://test.salesforce.com`) is NOT an instance URL. `sfdx` docs do use these URLs as examples of `--instanceurl` but they do not explain that `sfdx` allows these URLs in lieu of *real* instance URLs to make it easier for end-users. It's an optimization that could (and does in your case) fail.

That is, if your `--instanceurl` is one of the two URLs mentioned above, `sfdx` will authorize your request via whatever method (e.g. JWT) using one of these two service endpoints and then retrieve an *actual* instance URL from the authorization response.  The authorization can proceed against login.s.c or test.s.c but subsequent calls made by `sfdx` need a real instance URL.

How could it fail? `sfdx` performs a DNS lookup on the instance URL to make sure it's valid. If the lookup fails, it will keep on trucking with generic login.s.c/test.s.c URL. This will lead to `Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set` error.

Comment: It makes sense that login.salesforce.com is not actually an `--instanceurl`. What's also interesting in this Jenkins environment is that when I attempt `ping login.salesforce.com` I'm getting back `ping: unknown host login.salesforce.com` - that's obviously not the case in all other environments where generic url worked fine.